# Syntax Error: Unexpected '.' in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an error like

> Type: ParseError
>
> Message: syntax error, unexpected '.'
>
> Filename: /opt/lampp/htdocs/cctv/application/views/edit_camera.php

where's my error?

```
<div style="margin-top: " class="form-group">
  <label>Terminal</label>
  <select class="form-control input-lg" id="required" name='id_terminal' data-placeholder="Pilih transaksi">
   <?php foreach ($get_camera as $cam) { 
     if ($cam->id_camera == $this->uri->segment(3)) {
       foreach ($terminal as $ter) { 
         if($ter->id_terminal == $cam->id_terminal) { ?>
           <?php echo "<option ".($cam->id_terminal == $ter->id_terminal ? ." selected='selected'".).">".$ter->nama_terminal."</option>" ?>
        <?php   }
       }
     } ?>
   <?php } ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It would help if you had said which is line 70, but I think it's the `.`. in `id_terminal ? ." selected` (after the ?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

`<?php echo "<option ".($cam->id_terminal == $ter->id_terminal ? ." selected='selected'".).">".$ter->nama_terminal."</option>" ?>`

should be changed to

`<?php echo "<option ".($cam->id_terminal == $ter->id_terminal ? " selected='selected'" : '').">".$ter->nama_terminal."</option>" ?>`

You have simply added too much "." for string concatenation, and missed the ":" on the ternary operator.

Comment: great @rizkyalviandra, you should accept the answer, then :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way, there is issue with the way you concatenat string :

```
<div style="margin-top: " class="form-group">
    <label>Terminal</label>
    <select class="form-control input-lg" id="required" name='id_terminal' data-placeholder="Pilih transaksi">
    <?php 
        foreach ($get_camera as $cam) { 
            if ($cam->id_camera == $this->uri->segment(3)) {
                foreach ($terminal as $ter) { 
                    if($ter->id_terminal == $cam->id_terminal) {
                        echo "<option ".($cam->id_terminal == $ter->id_terminal ? " selected='selected'":'').">".$ter->nama_terminal."</option>";
                     }
                }
            } 
        } 
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
```